# Почему после освобождения памяти переменная не равна нулю?

Tags: c

Не могу сам разобраться, как правильно освободить память.
Есть код:

```
typedef struct user
{
  char *name;
}user_t;

extern user_t *usr;

int main()
{
  user_t *usr = (user_t*)malloc(sizeof(user_t));

  if(usr->name)
    printf("usr->name != NULL\n");
  else
    printf("usr->name == NULL\n");

  printf("usr->name: %s\n", usr->name);

  char *_name = "Andrey";
  usr->name = malloc(strlen(_name) + 1);
  strcpy(usr->name, _name);

  printf("usr->name: %s\n", usr->name);

  if(usr->name)
    printf("usr->name != NULL\n");
  else
    printf("usr->name == NULL\n");

  free(usr->name);

  if(usr->name)
    printf("usr->name != NULL\n");
  else
    printf("usr->name == NULL\n");

  printf("usr->name: %s\n", usr->name);

  return 0;
}
```

Почему после освобождения памяти переменная usr->name != NULL?

Comment: Потому что `free()` получает **значение** указателя, и освобождает память. Вы же не ждете, например, что для функции `void zero(int x){ x = 0; }` после вызова `zero(5)` ваше 5 станет равно 0? :)

Comment: Понял, в таком случае, как будет правильнее осуществлять проверку переменной?

Comment: По переменной вы не проверите, освобождена ли память. Просто - вызвали `free()` - значит, освободили :) И, кстати, в вашем коде `user_t *usr = (user_t*)malloc(sizeof(user_t));

  if(usr->name) ....` `usr->name` может содержать любой мусор, поведение не определено.

Comment: @Andreyddk в смысле? Вам надо освободить, вы вызвали `free()`, память освободилась и вы можете быть спокойны. Распространённый паттерн - присвоить после этого указателю `NULL` для больше надёжности.

Comment: Просто пытаюсь понять как осуществлять проверку переменной на наличие информации) Получается нужно после освобождения памяти переменной присвоить ей значение NULL?

Comment: Вы не можете присваивать значения в памяти, которая освобождена. Также не имеет смысла устанавливать какие-либо значения в памяти, которая сразу же после предыдущих действий будет освобождена (мы пока не говорим за многопоточность).

Comment: Посему остаётся только один способ — проверять сам указатель на область памяти, но не значения по нему.

Comment: не переменной присваивать нулл, а указателю на неё. вполне корректно даже после free

Comment: Понял, благодарю всех за помощь)